# spring junits are not reconized in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, testng

I have a test case which looks like the following

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:chartContext-test.xml" })
@Component("allocationChartTest")
public class ChartServiceUnitTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
```

and I have imports which look like the following

```
org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
```

so basically i am using spring junits it is nothing to do with junit 4 or 3
When i right click on the class it does not give an option called run as junit
not sure what needs to be added scr/mian/java and src/main/test both are included in my source..
Can some one give an idea why it is is giving me an option ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does your test class have the `@Component` annotation? Anyhow, you need to [install TestNG in Eclipse](http://testng.org/doc/download.html). Are you familiar with tutorials such as this one: http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-testing-support-testng?